# Why is this Golang code to convert a string to an integer failing?

Tags: go

This should have been simple:

```
strconv.Atoi("1250000.0000")
```

This results in an error:

> 0 strconv.ParseInt: parsing "1250000.0000": invalid syntax

Any clues?

Comment: Have you imported the strconv package ?

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Comment: This doesn't look like an integer. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: It already returned the error to you directly, `invalid syntax`. You are passing a floating point number to a function that expects to parse integers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Atoi` works only for strings that can be parsed as integers.

What you need is [parseFloat](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseFloat)

Answer (score 1):

What dystroy said is true, but keep in mind that floats are inprecise and you could get an incorrect answer that way. In your case you can simply split the string on the period and then use `Atoi` on that.

```
strconv.Atoi(strings.Split("1250000.0000", ".")[0])
```

Comment: You're missing the `, "."` in the params to `strings.Split()` (and fixing that is less than six chars change, so StackOverflow won't accept the edit)